# Crowdsale - Invalid implicit conversion from contract IERC20 to contract ERC20 requested

Tags: contract-development, openzeppelin, crowdsale, truffle-compile

I am using ^0.8.0 version of solidity compiler and trying to add crowdsale smart contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./Crowdsale.sol";

contract MyTokenSale is Crowdsale {
    constructor(
        uint256 rate, // rate in TKNbits
        address payable wallet,
        IERC20 token
    ) Crowdsale(rate, wallet, token) {}
}
```

And here is also part of code from **Crowdsale** contract

```
    constructor(
        uint256 _rate,
        address _wallet,
        ERC20 _token
    ) {
        require(_rate > 0);
        require(_wallet != address(0));
        require(address(token) != address(0));

        rate = _rate;
        wallet = _wallet;
        token = _token;
    }
```

The Crowdsale contract I took from https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/2.x/crowdsales
But this line `Crowdsale(rate, wallet, token)` catch an error with *token* as
`TypeError: Invalid type for argument in modifier invocation. Invalid implicit conversion from contract IERC20 to contract ERC20 requested.`

Maybe, I can somehow convert IERC20 to ERC20 or any else solutions??

Answer (score 0):

Change IERC20 token in MyTokenSale contract to ERC20 token.